# How to make HTTP request to HereUS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the follower feed of an user via HereUS API. It will be the main page of my application. Application is a client for HereUS.

I am not able to make HTTP request with React. URL, method, headers and data is how it must be; controlled with copy-paste to Python 3 script and it worked.

Code:

```js
fetch('https://hereus.pythonanywhere.com/API/FEED_FOLLOWS', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: 'username@domain',
    password: 'password'
  })
})
  .then(res => {
    return res.json()
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

Response content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>\n
```

I expected:

```
{data: [{community: '', date_created: 'Sat, 25 Jun 2022 12:20:18 GMT', email: 'islekcaganmert@barsposta.com', id: 1, text: '"Ne Mutlu Türküm Diyene" -Mustafa Kemal ATATÜRK', username: 'Çağan Mert İŞLEK'}]}
```

Comment: Try adding the closing arrow after the doc type: <!DOCTYPE HTML>.  That's what the error message seems to be.

Comment: You _are_ able to make an HTTP request. It's apparently not a _valid_ one, but that's between you and the server.

Comment: @dram95 firstly that's not correct _in HTML_ (it's a "legacy string" per e.g. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-doctype), but secondly the problem is that it's HTML **not JSON**.

Comment: @dram95 I am not trying to get HTML response, unfortunately I am taking a HTML response. My goal is taking a json like I expected. I added no HTML code to my script.